# UPDATE SQLITE with multiple column values

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

for (int i = 0; i < subjectsforGrades.size(); i++) {

```
                        sql2 = "UPDATE " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_4_NAME
                                + " SET "
                                + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_4_COL_3 + " = " + selectedGrades.get(i)
                                + " , "
                                + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_4_COL_4  + " = " + gpaforSubjects.get(i)
                                + " WHERE "
                                + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_4_COL_2 + " = " + subjectsforGrades.get(i);

                        dbHelper.executeQuery(sql2);
                    }
```

public void executeQuery(String sql) {

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL(sql);
}
```

subjectsforGrades, selectedGrades, gpaforSubjects are arraylists

08-22 11:37:33.157  23019-23019/com.example.sasankapabasara.pdmaplication E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near ",": syntax error

```
08-22 11:37:33.157  23019-23019/com.example.sasankapabasara.pdmaplication D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM

08-22 11:37:33.157  23019-23019/com.example.sasankapabasara.pdmaplication W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ff6930)

08-22 11:37:33.177  23019-23019/com.example.sasankapabasara.pdmaplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main



    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE gpa SET grade = A+ , gpa = 4.0 WHERE subid = 1
```

Comment: can you put your query?

Comment: sql2 = "UPDATE " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_4_NAME
                  + " SET "
                  + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_4_COL_3 + " = " + selectedGrades.get(i) 
    + " , " +DatabaseHelper.TABLE_4_COL_4  
    + " = " + gpaforSubjects.get(i)
                  + " WHERE "
                  + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_4_COL_2 + " = " + subjectsforGrades.get(i);

Comment: I have tried ", "......" , "..... " ," but nothing works

Comment: I think `A+` it should enclosed in single or double quote.

Comment: see `SQLiteDatabase#update(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)` how do you use it?

Comment: I'm passing it as a String value

Comment: which method you are calling for update? put that code in your question.

Comment: what a "String value"??? post the code how you are using `SQLiteDatabase#update`

Comment: `SQLiteDatabase#execSQL(String sql)`

"Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement that returns data.

It has no means to return any data (such as the number of affected rows). Instead, you're encouraged to use insert(String, String, ContentValues), **update(String, ContentValues, String, String[])**, et al, when possible."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should be like this (Use "AND' instead of ",")

```
sql2 = "UPDATE " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_4_NAME + " SET " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_4_COL_3 + " = '" + selectedGrades.get(i) + "' AND " +DatabaseHelper.TABLE_4_COL_4 + " = '" + gpaforSubjects.get(i) + "' WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_4_COL_2 + " = '" + subjectsforGrades.get(i)+"'";
```

Comment: Who gives this negative voting? What's the problem with this answer?
If don't have dare to face then go and watch Pogo (for Negative voters.)

Answer (score 0):

```
sql2 = "UPDATE " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_4_NAME + " SET " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_4_COL_3 + " = '" + selectedGrades.get(i) + "' , " +DatabaseHelper.TABLE_4_COL_4 + " = '" + gpaforSubjects.get(i) + "' WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_4_COL_2 + " = '" + subjectsforGrades.get(i)+"'";
```